# Add Forecast Month Data Based on LY Month values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, scheduling, agent

In my use case I need to append a new forecast month based on LY values in my SQL Server table x.

This is my approach for now: create a separate table y to load the LY values from table x, do my transformations (YYMMM + 1 year) and append back to table x.

[image: Use Case Screenshot with data structure]

SQL table name:
SQL_Forecast

Is there a possibility to modify the data while doing the insert (or other statement to add data)?

The main issue is that if I copy the data first, the new month value and the ly values will get overwritten.

Any feedback help is welcome,

Comment: You can modify data in a query, yes. `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable SELECT YourColumn +1 FROM dbo.OtherTable;` would insert the column `YourColumn` from the table `dbo.OtterTable` into the table `YourTable`, but all the values would be 1 greater than the source. What is it your *actually* asking here. What isn't working in the attempts you have made? What *were* those attempts? What does this qusetion have to do with scheduling, Visual Studio and (SQL Server?) Agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE:

```
with to_insert as (
      <complicated query here>
     )
insert into x ( . . . )  -- column list here
    select . . . 
    from to_insert;
```